# Using database columns data in a parameter and then in function (or use anywhere in the model)

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I want to import a schedule consisting of patient arrival time and their id and their type and simulate it n times, to check the performance metrics. I have imported a table ( half of it) in a database [see table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kOlk.png), and parameters mapping to it [parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdja4.png) [source block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWcIT.png), and generated arrivals according to the arrival date in the table.

I want to set service time in service block based on what patient type it is. I used patType paprameter and wrote this in delaytime (agent.patType == A ? 59.5+46*beta(0.331,1.44):(agent.patType == B ? poisson(42.1): triangular(9.5, 20, 29.5))), but it shows error A and B cannot be resolved to a variable. I also tried importing other table only with service times and patient type, but didn't worked. I am stuck at this initial step of running schedule for a day, any help would be really very helpful. There might be already answered queries similar to this but a idea to this problem will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the parameter `patType` of type String? Then the formula should be `(agent.patType.equals("A") ? 59.5+46*beta(0.331,1.44):(agent.patType.equals("B") ? poisson(42.1): triangular(9.5, 20, 29.5)))`

You forgot to put your String values between double quotes and AnyLogic thought they were variables. Also it's best to use the `.equals()` method for comparing Strings instead of the `==` operator.